# How to import and read excel rows in Julia?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I have a dataset like the following picture and want to read and extract each cell and assign them into parameters in an optimization model. For example, considering only one part of a row:

```
ID,  Min, speed, Distance, Time Latitude, Longitude 
1   2506  23271  11.62968  17.7 -37.731     144.898
```

Every row depicts a persons' information. So, is it better to define a dictionary of person and put all these into that? Or is it better to define a tuple? Arrays(like below)?

```
for i in 1:n_people
    person_id = i     
    push!(requests, Request(ID[i], Min[i], speed[i], Distance[i], Latitude[i], Longitude[i]))
end
```

In any case, how can I access (extract), let's say, distance for that person?
I mean, I need to have a set of people in my model like
`people[i]` and then for each of these connect them to their information (model parameters) like person's 'i' distance, speed,... and then compare them with person `j`.
What is the best way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since JuMP is agnostic to the format of the input data, the answer is: it depends on what you want to do with it. Pick whatever makes the most sense to you.

There are a few data related tutorials that address how to read data into a DataFrame and use that to create JuMP variables and constraints. Reading those is a good next step:

https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/getting_started/getting_started_with_data_and_plotting/

https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/linear/diet/

Comment: Hi @Oscar Dowson thanks. I like to have access to each cell and assign them to each person's. for instace if I want to know about speed of ith person, just have a possiblity to say speed[i]

Comment: Is this for JuMP or just Julia in general? After reading into a data frame, you can go `df.speed[i]`. Here's the documentation: https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/